# Clicks on main page turn unclickable. Issue fixed after clearing browser history

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. Using thrive architect to design main landing page. I ran into an issue today while adding a new blog. All the links on the main page turned unclickable. Links in the menu worked fine. I tried accessing the blog on phone. Noticed same issue. The issue was fixed on my computer browser and phone after I deleted browser history of last 24 hours. I am concerned I will loose return traffic if my readers experience the same issue and do not bother clearing the history. Has anyone ran into similar issue or have any suggestions. Website is https://lifemomma.com/

Comment: we have checked it. but the blog link is working.